# unable to cout string in C++

Tags: c++, string, function, variables

I am new to programming and I can only use C++. I have been working on an RPG, and for some reason I can't get the program to print out the value that I set a string to. I started by defining the string "weapon" in void main.

```
void main()
{
string weapon;
cin >> weapon;
if(weapon = "A")
{
weapon == "sword";
}
}
```

I had the code sort of like this and I had a function above it that uses "weapon" (which was set to sword as you can see from the code above) at the end of something that I had it print out, but that was in the function (which was above the void main) so in  order to get both to be defined variables I had to define them in both the void main and the function, but when I do that, nothing appears in the program when it's run. I had everything written correctly (what I put above is just an example) but the only way that it doesn't create an error is by defining it in both parts of the code. It says that one of them hasn't been defined yet so I defined it both the function and the void main. Why isn't it working? How do I fix it?
Thanks

P.S. I did include the string library and namespace.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code.

Comment: You have `=` and `==` mixed up.

Comment: I don't know where to start. Unfortunately, neither do you!

Comment: I'm glad you only work with swords and not [nuclear rockets](http://pastebin.com/6gQqTRuw).

Comment: Unrelated: `main` must return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"...

Comment: If what you showed is your complete code, I can tell you why it fails to output a string: You have no output statement anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least as I read it, you have code vaguely like this:

```
void f() { 
    string weapon;
    cout << weapon;
}

int main(){ 
    string weapon = "sword";
    f();
}
```

...and the problem is that the value you're assigning to `weapon` in `main` isn't being used used when you call `f`.

Assuming that's roughly correct, what you're seeing is normal, expected behavior. The `weapon` you've defined in `main` is a separate variable from the `weapon` you define in `f`. Assigning a value to one has no effect on the other.

To get the desired effect, you need to "pass" the value from one to the other as a parameter:

```
void f(string w) { 
    cout << w;
}

int main() { 
   string weapon = "sword";
   f(weapon);
}
```

This way, calling `f` gives it a copy of the current value that the `weapon` in `main` has been assigned, so `f` can use that same value.

Answer (score 6):

`void main()` is illegal. It must be `int main()`, though some compilers will erroneously accept `void main()`.

```
if(weapon = "A")
{
weapon == "sword";
}
```

It looks like you have this backwards. The single `operator=` sets `weapon` to the constant `"A"`, regardless of what the user entered. The comparison `operator==` compares `weapon` with the constant `"sword"` and promptly discards that result. Perhaps you meant to use comparison in the `if` and assignment in the body of the `if`?

Answer (score 5):

You're using `=` where you need `==`, and vice versa. Should be:

```
if(weapon == "A") { weapon = "sword"; }
```

Comment: +1 -- don't know what others' problem is.

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't answer the question. If this were the problem, then the program would print "A".

Comment: @Beta: Unless one of the `if`s in the real code tries to "compare" to empty string.

Comment: @Beta You can't know that because OP didn't show how and where they're printing. Reading the text under the code, I'd say that this is probably the least of OP's problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should look up for online tutorial, programming in C++. That is a good place to get started. Or buy a book on C++ programming.